# How to set relativelayout height equal to its width?

Tags: java, android

I searched a lot to find out how its gonna work and I got nothing.
I found some java code to do it dynamically but didn't work ant of theme and when opening the program, show a force close.
this is my code:

```
<LinearLayout android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectengle2" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlv2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectengle" >
    </RelativeLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see I created a rectangle shape and used it in a relative layout with a lineaer layout as parent and i splitted that linear layout verticali to two part for each relative layout.
now i want to set these relative layout height equal to its width to get a pure square rectangle.
i tried many way but ... can help me any guy please?? thnaks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I myself found out what to do in this situation. so i'm gonna explain how to solve for those who have or will have my problem.
in my xml ui file I set layout_weight=1 for a pair of relative layout that were in a linear layout to be splitted in the screen and actually width of each of them be the half of my screen width. my problem was about height and i tried many java codes to set relative layout height equals to its width.
finally i calculated the screen width in "DP" Term and set every relative layout's height to this. this is the solved code:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        
    float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    RelativeLayout Rl1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlv1);
    Rl1.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (dpWidth);

    RelativeLayout Rl2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlv2);
    Rl2.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (dpWidth);
```

so i got a pure square! Enjoy it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution, imo, is to subclass RelativeLayout, and override onMeasure, providing to the super the same size for width and height. For instance

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

as pointed out by @ZakTaccardi, declare it in your layout like

```
<com.example.subclassrelativelayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I cant figure it out how to use. how should i call my layout in this code you wrote?

Comment: This is the better answer.

You can reference your new subclass using your fully qualified class name in the XML. So instead of `<RelativeLayout/>`, use `<com.example.subclassrelativelayout/>`

Comment: @ZakTaccardi for your input

Comment: amazing, the best solution, and pretty simple