# How to keep a TextView square?

Tags: android, layout, view

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203344/1145666), which makes sure the aspect ratio is preserved of the an `ImageView`.

How would I be able to do that with a `TextView` with a background drawable? I have this `TextView`:

```
       <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/tvCount"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_notify"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>
```

and this is my background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <!-- The fill color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    <!-- Just to add a border -->
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:width="2dp"
        />
</shape>
```

How to make sure the `TextView` stays square (and the background thus a perfect circle?).

Comment: subclass it, and override onMeasure

Comment: @Blackbelt could you elaborate on that? I tried subclassing it and overriding `onMeasure`, but I get some strange values when reading height and width I get in that call.

Comment: If you don't need anything fancy [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770142/how-to-set-relativelayout-height-equal-to-its-width) should do it

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:gravity="center"` and `android:padding="@dimen/circle_radius`. Define `circle_radius` dimen in dimens.xml file.

Comment: I never used the `dimen.xml` file, how would I define that ?

Comment: It is resource file under values folder.

Comment: I know that, but how should I define a circular radius in there? Just putting `padding="5sp"` will still make it oval if the width is larger than the height.

Comment: Yes you can.. I recommend not hard coding it.

Comment: Use  `<size android:height="20dp"android:width="20dp"/>` inside <shape> tag

Comment: Still makes it oval if the text becomes larger.

Comment: Do you want text in single line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104664/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-malwinder).

Answer (score 1):

Use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` in TextView

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/tvCount"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_notify"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>
```